# AggregateRating Google+ For services of own product?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, google-plus

I have a client which is asking If I could enable "stars" in their search results. What they actually want is the Google+ Reviews rating to show up on their profile (it's all 5 stars that's why). As I've been searching the web it seems I can use AggregateRating for this. But it seems dirty.

What are options for this, can I implement certain snippets from Google+ itself? Is there something they can configure in their Google+ Profile?

I don't feel happy with just adding a static 5/5 review like that.

Comment: If that tool works why wouldn't you use it? What makes it feel "dirty"?

Comment: I'm not using any tools, but It would be me setting up a default 5/5 stars value. It's not live so it could be "Misleading", that's my problem with it.